# ¿Cómo capitalizar cualquier letra especificada?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código, y lo que intento es agregar un método a la clase `String`, el método lo que hace es recibir un parámetro y este parámetro le indica al código dentro de la función cual indice de la String debe ser capitalizada(pasada a mayúscula), pero no me funciona, ¿Por qué? ¿Cuál es el error en mi forma de pensar?

```js
String.prototype.capitalize = function(index){
  
  var toArray = this.split(" "),
      j       = 0,
      maxArray= toArray.length,
      returnedWord = [];
  
  for(;j<maxArray;j++){
    if(j == index) returnedWord[j] = toArray[j].substring(index-1,index).toUppercase(); // Si el indice actual del array es igual al indice pasado como parametro, se reemplaza esa letra por mayuscula
    returnedWord[j] += toArray[j].slice(index); // desde index hacia delante
  }
  
  return returnedWord;
  
  
};

var i = 'capitalizando caulquier letra'.capitalize(4);
console.log(i);
```

***Pero no me resulta, y me sale 'undefined' y luego el extracto de la palabra***

Comment: Creo que estás intentando capitalizar/volver mayúscula una palabra completa, no una letra: `var toArray = this.split(" ")` ¿ese es tu objetivo?

Comment: El problema es que en tu ciclo, `j` solo recorre el arreglo y tú lo estás considerando como si estuvieras recorriendo el string, tienes que usar un `for` anidado, donde ahora si recorras la cadena y encuentres el índice que estás buscando y hagas el `substring`, seguido de `toUpperCase`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dos cosas están mal en el acercamiento para resolver tu problema:

- Tu ciclo `j` solamente esta recorriendo los elementos de tu arreglo, y lo estás considerando como si estuvieras recorriendo los elementos de cada palabra, para eso requieres de un nuevo ciclo anidado.
- Las cadenas de caracteres son inmutables, es decir una vez declaradas no pueden ser cambiadas de ninguna forma, es decir hacer justo lo que quieres, tomar una letra de la cadena y transformarla a mayúsculas, sin afectar el resto de la cadena, este problema se ataca creando un nuevo string que contenga un `substring` hasta donde llegues a la letra que quieres pasar a mayúsculas, concatenar la letra ya transformada a mayúscula, y finalmente concatenar el resto del string.

```js
String.prototype.capitalize = function(index){
  var self = this;
  var toArray = this.split(" "),
      maxArray= toArray.length,
      returnedWord = []
  for(var j=0;j<maxArray;j++){
    for (var i=0;i<toArray[j].length;i++){
     if (i == index){
            var newCapitalize = toArray[j].substring(index-1,index).toUpperCase();
            returnedWord.push(toArray[j].substring(0, index-1) + 
                             newCapitalize + 
                            toArray[j].substr(index));
      }
    }
  }
  return returnedWord;
};

var i = 'capitalizando caulquier letra'.capitalize(4);
console.log(i);
var j = 'nuevo ejemplo capitalización'.capitalize(2);
console.log(j);
```

Te dejo el ejemplo donde ya te imprime las cadenas de caracteres con sus respectivas letras en mayúsculas según el índice que se envió como parámetro a la función.

Comment: Intentando entenderlo, pero por qué hay que usar un bucle anidado?, si se supone que el array es la palabra, que haces al recorrer i<toArray[j] ? , cuál es la lógica de eso, por favor explicame más si puedes

Comment: Un string es un arreglo de caracteres, entonces cuando recorres `toArray[i]` estás recorriendo otro arreglo la palabra donde vas buscando el índice que recibes como parámetro para crear un nuevo arreglo, capitalizando la letra que se debe de capitalizar. Recuerda que una cosa es tu arreglo de palabras, y otra cosa es el tu palabra que es otro arreglo más.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que deseas es capitalizar el front, puedes hacerlo con CSS:

```css
    .capitalizando {
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
```

```html
<p class="capitalizando">hola, esta es un prueba para la hermandad de stack overflow en español, saludos bro!.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esta forma es muy breve, sencilla y funciona:

```
    String.prototype.capitalize = function(index){

        var letraMayuscula = this.charAt(index).toUpperCase();
        var palabraGenerada = this.slice(0, index) + letraMayuscula + this.slice(index+1, this.length);

        return palabraGenerada;
    };

    var i = "prueba".capitalize(1); //La función muestra la letra en la posición 1 en mayúscula
    console.log(i)
```